# Why python asyncio code stucks on the first concurrent task?

Tags: python-3.x, concurrency, python-asyncio

During the asyncio learning and tests, I've wrote the code below with 3 concurrent tasks.

```
import asyncio
from time import time

tasks_to_schedule = []
task_queue = []

class Test():
    def __init__(self, task_name, repeat_every):
        self.name = task_name
        self.repeat_every = repeat_every
        self.scheduled = 0

    def schedule(self, t_now):
        self.scheduled = t_now

    async def run(self):
        print(f'It is {self.name}')
        print(f'{self.name} running...')
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        print(f'{self.name} finished')

    def check_result(self):
        pass

    async def report(self):
        print(f'{self.name} report DONE')
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

def prepare_tasks():
    task_a = Test('Task A', 2)
    task_b = Test('Task B', 4)
    tasks_to_schedule.append(task_a)
    tasks_to_schedule.append(task_b)

async def scheduler():
    turn = 0
    while turn < 5:
        if tasks_to_schedule:
            print(f'***\t Turn {turn} \t***')
            task = tasks_to_schedule.pop(0)
            if task.scheduled < time():
                task_queue.append(task)
                print(f'adding task {task.name} to queue,\n queue size = {len(task_queue)}')
                turn += 1
            else:
                tasks_to_schedule.append(task)
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def worker(name):
    while True:
        if task_queue:
            task = task_queue.pop(0)
            print(f'Worker {name} - took task {task.name}')
            await task.run()
            await task.report()
            print(f'Worker {name} - task {task.name} completed, reschedule it')
            task.schedule(time())
            tasks_to_schedule.append(task)
        # await asyncio.sleep(1)       #Process stuck without this line

async def main():
    task_scheduler = asyncio.create_task(scheduler())
    worker1 = asyncio.create_task(worker(1))
    worker2 = asyncio.create_task(worker(2))
    await asyncio.gather(task_scheduler, worker1, worker2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    prepare_tasks()
    asyncio.run(main())
```

The problem in process stuck after "Task A running...", the only output is:

```
***      Turn 0         ***
adding task Task A to queue,
 queue size = 1
Worker 1 - took task Task A
It is Task A
Task A running...
```

After several tries, I've noticed, that with the additional "await asyncio.sleep(1)" line in the end of the loop inside "worker" func the process run correctly without any stuck.

I wonder, what is the reason?

Could someone explain me, please, why this additional line change everything?

Platform: Python 3.9.4, Windows 10 x64, inside venv.

Comment: I've added an additional line after: async def worker(name):
    while True:
        print(f'{strftime("%X")}: worker loop')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added an additional line after:

```
 async def worker(name):
 while True:
     print(f'{strftime("%X")}: worker loop')   #this line
```

and I can see an endless worker loop in the output...
Now I see, the worker can't find task...

Solved :)